Weird soft lumps resin in vat, cut models, supports forming at edge of build plate out of nowhere, weird resin glued on models
I usually have a 97% success rate with this printer but after not using it for 2 months all the prints now fail with these many weird issues such as:

Many soft lumps of resin stuck to the bottom of the vat
Supports forming but I did not put anything there while in the slicer
Weird shape forming attached to the model itself
My model looked as if it was cut out of the build plate (although I have made absolutely sure that it fits perfectly on the build plate in the slicer)

what I have tried:

The first print I did had 80% UV power, 55 s bottom exposure, 30 um, and 3.3 exposure time. the result was weak supports with absolutely no models attached with weird lumps of resins attached to the supports and at the bottom of the vat
The second print I tried 80% UV power, 75 s bottom exposure, 50 um, and 4.1s exposure time and did a re-leveling to the build plate, but the photo above happened... (many weird lumps formed, and weirdly shaped bottom layer, cut model, support that are not supposed to be there just formed out of nowhere, etc.)

Additional info:

This is not a hollowed model
I exported the STL from Lychee and put it in Chitubox for slicing then straight to the printer
Using an Anycubic Photon Mono C

Before this happened I usually had a 95% success rate with the second print setting but now it failed so horribly after not using the printer for 2 months (yes I had made sure to stir up the resin well before printing).




